# need help simplifying boolean algebra exrpressions

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can someone walk me through simplifying the following expression?

$$a\lnot b\lnot s + ab \lnot s + \lnot abs + abs$$

help and advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, the first step is observing
\begin{align*}
(a \wedge \neg b \wedge \neg s) \vee (a \wedge b \wedge \neg s) & = (\neg s \wedge a) \wedge (\neg b \vee b) & \text{distrib., commut.} \\
&= (\neg s \wedge a) \wedge 1 & \text{complementation} \\
&= \neg s \wedge a & \text{identity}
\end{align*}
A similar simplification can be made to the right-hand side $(\neg a \wedge b \wedge s) \vee (a \wedge b \wedge s)$.

This leads me to $(\neg s \wedge a) \vee (b \wedge s)$ which doesn't seem to simplify more.